# Save a YAML Emitter content to a file with YAML-CPP

Tags: yaml-cpp

I just started playing around with yaml-cpp, I managed to build it properly and run some of the examples from the yaml-cpp wiki but I can't find a way to save my emitter to a file.

Is this not possible? I mean the PyYAML library has a 'dump' function for this. Is there no such functionality in yaml-cpp?
Is there some workaround to converting a yaml emitter to a stl stream and then dumping this to a yaml file?

Please let me know

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 9):

The function `Emitter::c_str()` returns a `NULL`-terminated C-style string (which you do not have to release), which you can then write to a file. For example:

```
YAML::Emitter emitter;
emitter << "Hello world!";

std::ofstream fout("file.yaml");
fout << emitter.c_str();
```

There is also `Emitter::size()`, which returns the number of bytes in that string, in case you want to do something more advanced and don't want to walk the string to find its length.

If you want to just dump a `Node` to a stream, there's a shortcut:

```
YAML::Node node = ...;
std::ofstream fout("file.yaml");
fout << node;
```

Comment: Just curious, how did you figure out this dumping method? Where do you learn these things. The documentation for `yaml-cpp` is pretty short.

Comment: @JustinLiang I wrote it :) - but you're right, the documentation is a bit short. It's on my TODO list, but, you know...

Comment: @JesseBeder Is there a way to save it in same order as `node`?

Comment: @JustinLiang - nope, not yet - see https://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/issues/detail?id=169

Comment: mmm, so even a large yaml file has to be stored in memory before dumping it to a file? Is there a way to build the yaml into the file directly?