# C++ YAML: How to edit/write to a node in a .yaml file

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

I am trying to write a function that will write/edit a node in my `.yaml` file using `yaml-cpp`. I kind of got it working as my code will edit the local copy. When I print out `_baseNode` it shows that the node has the value 5.4 in it. However, after exiting the function and checking my `.yaml` on my computer the value 5.4 is not there.

Here is my attempt (`_baseNode` is a private member of my class):

```
void ParametersServerPC::testFunc2() {

    boost::filesystem::path path(boost::filesystem::initial_path() / _parameterFileName);
    _baseNode = YAML::LoadFile(_parameterFileName);

    _baseNode["chip"]["clock_rate"]["3"] = 5.4;

    std::cout << _baseNode << std::endl;

}
```

For my second attempt, I created a `YAML::Node& baseNode`:

```
YAML::Node& baseNode = YAML::LoadFile(_parameterFileName);
```

but then I get this error:

```
invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'YAML::Node&' from an rvalue of type 'YAML::Node'
```

For those who are interested, the `.yaml` file looks like this:

```
chip:
  clock_rate:
    0: 1.0
    1: 1.0
    2: 1.0
    3: 3.0
    4: 1.0
```

I want to change the value mapped by `3` from 3.0 to 5.4.

Comment: What do you expect `LoadFile` to do? It's pretty clear that it loads the data into memory and does not provide a magical interface to the filesystem. You have to explicitly write the changed tree back to the filesystem using the `Emitter` API, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342355/save-a-yaml-emitter-content-to-a-file-with-yaml-cpp.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense. I thought based on the tutorial (https://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/wiki/Tutorial#Building_Nodes) I could just build nodes onto the file. I will look into this `Emitter` API then, cheers :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like what @filmor said in the comments, `LoadFile` only loads the data into memory and does not provide an interface to the filesystem.

Thus, edit a `.yaml` file, you must first edit the root node of the file and dump it back into the file like so:

```
YAML::Node node, _baseNode = YAML::LoadFile("file.yaml"); // gets the root node
_baseNode["change"]["this"]["node"] = "newvalue"; // edit one of the nodes 
std::ofstream fout("fileUpdate.yaml"); 
fout << _baseNode; // dump it back into the file
```